# ExtJS Store not loading correctly?

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, model

I have the following model,

```
Ext.define('Forecaster.model.WeatherDay', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'version', 
            type : 'string',
            mapping : 'version'//'forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday.date.pretty'
        }
    ]
});
```

Which is being used by the following store :

```
Ext.define('Forecaster.store.WeatherDay', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    model : 'Forecaster.model.WeatherDay',
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'jsonp',
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/[apiKEY]/forecast10day/q/11432.json',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty : 'response'
        }
    }
});
```

But the store is empty. When I do the following :

```
console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData);
```

Following is printed out(so the store is receiving data):

[image]

Which corresponds to the following JSON that I am receiving:

```
"response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast10day": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"5:18 PM EDT",
        "forecastday": [
        {
        "period":0,
        "icon":"cloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/cloudy.gif",
         ...more of the response...
```

What am I doing wrong in the mapping to the model phase since I am clearly receiving the data but the store is empty(getCount() returns 0) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your not setting the rootProperty correctly.
The rootProperty should be the one that in the response is pointing to an array of WeatherDay models.
Something like:

```
rootProperty: 'forecasts'
```

server response: `{forecasts: [{version: "some version"},{version: "some other version"}]}`

If the response you want is nested you can navigate like this:

```
rootProperty: 'response.forecasts'
```

server response: `{response: {forecasts: [{version: "some version"},{version: "some other version"}] }}`